# Applying style to actions list using React Native vector-icons

Tags: react-native

I'm building an Android application using React Native, and I'm using [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) to generate a toolbar header. Below is a snippet from my render-function showing how I've used the the vector-icons lib.

```
<Icon.ToolbarAndroid
        style={styles.toolbar}
        title="Home"
        titleColor="white"
        navIconName="md-menu"
        onIconClicked={this.toggleSideMenue.bind(this)}
        actions={[
          { title: 'AddPerson', ref : 'addPerson', iconName: 'md-person-add', show: 'always'},
          { title: 'Swap', iconName: 'md-swap', show: 'always'},
        ]}
        onActionSelected={(position) => this.onActionSelected(position)}
/>
```

I can easily apply styles to the toolbar itself, but my question is if there is a way to apply styles to the icons in the **actions** list? E.g. change icon color, rotation, size etc. I've tried the following but it does not seem to do anything:

```
{ title: 'Swap', style : {color : 'red'}, iconName: 'md-swap', show: 'always'},
```

Answer (score 0):

add `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';` in your js file

and change

```
actions={[
      { title: 'AddPerson', ref : 'addPerson', iconName: 'person-add', show: 'always'},
      { title: 'Swap', iconName: 'swap', show: 'always'},
    ]}
```

and change style for action icon impossible!

Comment: Icon is imported as `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons` which works fine for showing the icons. I omitted that from the code snippet, since that wasn't really my concern. Sad thing that icon style customisation isn't working in the actions list, should this answer be correct.

Comment: So, as for changing color icon the simple fix is just to add  the **iconColor**  parameter, eg:  

`{ title: 'Swap', iconName: 'swap', show: 'always', iconColor : 'red'}`. 

Other types of custom css-like styling, such as changing opacity, rotation etc. does not seem to be supported in the **actions** list.